# Is there a way to share your custom app only with group of users in Rally?

Tags: sdk, rally

I would like to share my Rally custom app not just with certain projects but with certain group of people only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting idea, but there's not currently a way to do that directly.  You could add the app to your subscription level app catalog and have users individually install it on their own dashboards or private custom pages.  Or you could create a project, only give the target users access to it, and then share your page with the app on it with that project.  That's probably about as close as you can currently get...